# RxJs hot range observable

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to create a hot range observable. This means that when I have an observer observering the observable after a certain timeout, it should not receive the values that have already been published. I have created the following program:

```
import Rx from "rxjs/Rx";

var x =   Rx.Observable.range(1,10).share()


x.subscribe(x => {
    print('1: ' + x);
  });

setTimeout(() => {
  x.subscribe(x => {
    print('2: ' + x);
  });
}, 1000);

  function print(x) {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerText = x;
    document.body.appendChild(element)
  }
```

I expect this program to print 1 to 10, and then the second observable to print nothing, since the values 1 to 10 are produced within the first second. The expected output is shown below.

```
1: 1
1: 2
..
1:10
```

However, I see that it also prints all the values. Eventhough I have put the share() operator behind it. The output is shown below.

```
1: 1
..
1: 10
2: 1
..
2: 10
```

Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

`share` returns an observable that's reference counted for subscriptions. When the reference count goes from zero to one, the shared observable subscribes to the source - in your case, to the `range` observable. And when the reference count drops back to zero, it unsubscribes from the source.

The key point in your snippet is that `range` emits it's values synchronously and then completes. And the completion effects an unsubscription from the shared observable and that sees the reference count drop back to zero - which sees the shared observable unsubscribe from its source.

If you replace `share` with `publish` you should see the behaviour you expected:

```
var x =   Rx.Observable.range(1,10).publish();
x.subscribe(x => print('1: ' + x));
x.connect();
```

`publish` returns a `ConnectableObservable` which is not reference counted and provides a `connect` method that can be called to explicitly connect - i.e. subscribe - to the source.

Comment: Great ! Thank you. I'm sharing a stackblitz that helped me better understand your answer : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-51175131